# Good designer or not

Tags: design-principles, designers

How do i know if I'm a good designer or my designs could be underestimated?

[image]

Comment: If you're asking the question, you're already better than most bad designers.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell as you've only provided one example of your work. Looking at it, it's good. Better than a lot of crap out there. But it's not "wow". ("Wow" is not easy. It takes a lot of work.)

What separates good designers from bad ones is

- Originality
- Understanding colours
- Alignment and distribution
- Balance

You seem to have to some level all of these in your card. I had a look at your portfolio on behance, your designs are good. There are few really good ones.

Reading your other comments, I can understand why your not being hired. Your designs have an ethnic feel to them. They also look a little similar, for example the colours are mostly reds pinks and oranges. You need to diversify a little more. People looking at your portfolio might feel your skill set is limited to this style.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful comment, i just need criticism because i'm home from 2013 due to pregnancy and being a mum and i just moved to Austria and started to look for a job and i want evaluation because i really can't be always the only one who evaluate myself . here is a link of my portfolio on Behance website https://www.behance.net/gallery/48124455/graphic-design-projects  i'd like to have a look and i'm waiting for feedback. thank u

Comment: Originality is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Design is naturally a highly subjective field so there may be no *right* answer to this question. However, a commentary on the technical aspects of your work might be more suitable for the format of this site. This will also be difficult from the one sample you've provided (although it looks like clean design work to me).

If I can take a different angle, I think what you might be looking for is *confidence.* This is something that can only be attained through a devotion to your craft, disciplined practice and industry experience (i.e; time). With patience you'll eventually wean out bad habits/practices and gain confidence that you're making the right decisions whether they're applied to the technical aspects of your designs or to the business side of dealing with clients. Keep in mind that being a *good designer* is also about knowing what the *wrong* answers are and how to avoid those pitfalls.

**One final note:** Doubt will always rear it's ugly head from time to time, but I always find the best way to deal with the "bully" is to confront it, defeat it, and put it in the proverbial rear view mirror. This too will serve to build confidence. Keep working hard and you'll have that designer swagger before you know it.

Comment: it's totally right analysis. it's exactly what i need confidence but i can't have it without more reviews from many designers because i think I'm okay but i need real evaluation, i want to improve my skills in the right way. i know that maybe i'm not so creative but i have the elements and i'v learned art and design together. i'v applied to many jobs here in Austria and i'v been neglected so i'm a little bit confused about my skills and i want to know honestly i'm not good enough or it's just because i have no work experience here in Austria cause i'm Egyptian and my experience is in Egypt !

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful comment, i'd like that you have a look on my work on Behance https://www.behance.net/gallery/48124455/graphic-design-projects

Comment: @Heba, I have looked at your Behance and seriously, you have no need to worry. It looks worked-through and intended. I work at an offset print shop and I see people making a living as designers with half your skills. So you have the skills and then you can concentrate on style. Both about the style of your individual customers and your own personal style. Finding the right balance is important. I do understand how moving to another country can be confusing. I don't know if your designs look Austrian, but most of your designs could be used in Denmark, where I am from.

Comment: I did all my designs in Egypt, and for Austria i don't know if it's look like their style or not, i already had a look over many Austrian designs and advertisings, my experience also not only about designing it's about finalizing the design to be printed if it stationary or outdoor printing, i learned printing techniques if it's CMYK or for banners and vinyls or flexo printing so i don't know should i refer to that in my job letter? Or i don't be hired just because my experience not in Austrian market!

Comment: I agree with completely with @Mads Wolff. Your portfolio has some strong work in it. It's tough finding work as a stranger in a new place. Unfortunately, good work doesn't always speak for itself in these situations. One thing that can help is doing a google search to find some designer/artist communities to join and start building a network in your new region. In addition to that, just keep creating and devoting yourself to your craft. Best of luck!